# Different definitions of an ergodic stationary process

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

From page 3 of [a note](http://www.cemfi.es/~bonhomme/Cours_Econ_web/Chap4.pdf):

> **A stationary process is ergodic** if any two variables positioned far
>   apart in the sequence are almost independently distributed.
>
> A formal definition is the following: $\{w_t\}$ is ergodic if for any two bounded functions
>   $f$ in $(k + 1)$ variables and $g$ in $(l + 1)$ variables:
>   $$\lim_{N \to \infty} |E(f(w_t, ..., w_{t+k})g(W_{t+N}, ..., w_{t+N+l}))|-
> |E(f(w_t, ..., w_{t+k}))| |E(g(W_{t+N}, ..., w_{t+N+l}))| =0.$$

This definition of ergodicity can also apply to wide-sense stationary processes, does it?

This definition of ergodicity seems more similar to mixing than to ergodicity. So is it actually a type of mixing for (wide-sense) stationary processes?

Is this definition of ergodicity for a stationary process, same as [the mean-square ergodicity in the first and second moment for  wide-sense stationary processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process#Specific_definitions), or [ergodicity for a measure-preserving mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Ergodic_transformations)?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: By "wide-sense stationary" you mean stationary correlation ?

Comment: "wide-sense stationary" is defined for a process so that its first and second moments don't change over its index